# What is the quote from Beowulf that says Grendel can't be harmed by weapons?

Tags: beowulf

I'm doing an essay for school and Ineed the quote and page number for where it's located

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's "help me do my homework."

Comment: @Ward - Homework questions are [perfectly fine here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/how-do-we-feel-about-homework-questions). If you feel differently, please put an answer onto meta so that the community can downvote the hell out of it.

Comment: Thank you for the salutary reminder, Valorum.  I was all set to whack this Question, but of course you are correct.  That doesn't make me any more inclined to do someone else's bare minimum of work for them (I know Beowulf fairly well)... but I won't downvote it in its capacity as a thing with a question-mark at the end.